# cron like scheduling with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am playing / learning python now of 1 week - so I am quite new.
I implemented successfully a working Telegram Bot using *python-telegram-bot*.
I created a working script using APScheduler without the bot and I would like to implement the same scheduling for my bot.

Working without the bot:

```
sched = BackgroundScheduler()
sched.add_job(my_funct, 'cron', day_of_week = 'mon-fri,sun', hour='11,15,19,23', minute = 55)
```

Not working with the bot:

```
context.job_queue.run_custom(my_funct, 'cron', days = 'mon-fri,sun', hour='11,15,19,23', minute = 55)
```

I get "TypeError: run_custom() got an unexpected keyword argument ..." for all of the used keywords.
According to the [telegram-python-bot documentation](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a1/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html) the scheduler is based on APScheduler. But I did not find any clues on how to use the function correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're providing the keyword arguments the wrong way. According to the documentation link you included, the keyword arguments should be passed to `job_kwargs`.

Like this:

```py
context.job_queue.run_custom(
    my_funct,
    job_kwargs={
        'trigger': 'cron',
        'days': 'mon-fri,sun',
        'hour': '11,15,19,23',
        'minute': 55,
    },
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much  - it works, and I am a big step further in understanding python documentation :-)

Comment: Cool to hear. You can click the checkmark next to the answer to mark your problem as resolved :)